# Is there any CSS/HTML code to make a cursor work on Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: html, css

Is there any CSS/HTML code to make a cursor work on Mozilla Firefox?

the only cursor code I know is

```
<body style="cursor:url(link.cur);"></body>
```

but that only works for Internet Explorer (and others maybe, I don't know) but what I need is a code that works in MFirefox

EDIT: I know some people find this annoying but is for a page contest and since I have a page about pirates I wanted to have a pirate-related cursor. And plus, the people on that site do not find cursors annyoing -_-'

I tried the

```
BODY {cursor: url(cursor.cur), url(cursor/cursor.cur), default;}
```

code, and the

```
<body style="cursor:url(link.cur), default;"></body>
```

that was suggested (and some others) but it seems I'm doing something wrong cause it still doesn't work on FF D:

my cursor URL is 'http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=188' does that help?

Answer (score 5):

[Yes, there is](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/).

You need to add `, default` to the property list, like this:

```
<body style="cursor:url(link.cur), default;"></body>
```

[Demo](http://beradrian.users.sourceforge.net/articles/cursor.html).

However, you should not use custom cursors without a good reason; they're annoying.

Comment: ...and if you'd like to learn about all default cursors available, head [here](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_cursor.asp). This lowers the chance that users instantly press `Ctrl+W` at your webpage.

Comment: That's annoying. I'm glad not many people know how to do that.